# Spark Streaming Actions and transformation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In the below code **`statement 5`** is not giving the count of lines but **`statement 4`** is printing the lines why? 
How many action operations get performed in spark streaming? 
Is **`statement 6`** is not executed?

```
1) val conf =new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("learn")
2) val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf,Seconds(10))    
3) val lines  =ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",1234)
4) lines.print()   
5) lines.count()
6) ssc.start()
7) ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answers for your questions:

> Why **`Statement 5`** is not giving the count of lines in output but **`statement 4`** is printing the lines why?

In **`statement 5`** you are just calling a count on DStream. Count is a *transformation* that gets applied on DStream. It return a new DStream of single-element RDDs by counting the number of elements in each RDD of the source DStream. 

 If you want to print out the count of lines then you should use **`lines.count().print()`**. 
**`Statement 4`** is giving output because print call is an *action* which prints the results.

> How many **`action operations`** get performed in spark streaming?

In your above code only one action gets performed which is print(), applied in **`statement 4`**. Generally, arbitrary actions can be performed in the same task.

> Is **`statement 6`** is not executed?

**`Statement 6`** gets executed, starts the streaming/spark context and the receiver starts receiving the data from sources.